Git: "Not a valid object name HEAD"
I'm a Git novice and am testing some Git tool scripts via BATS (Bash Automated Testing System).
I'm getting the following error:
fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD

The test does the following setup before running the tooling script:
git remote add origin my_repo/.git  # Create repository
git switch --create main  # Create main branch
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit"  # Initial commit on main

git tag v11.0.0  # Create a tag on main

git switch --create release/12.0.0  # Create release branch
git commit --allow-empty -m "Commit for v12.0.0"  # Initial commit on release branch

git merge tags/v11.0.0  # Merge tag onto the release branch

git switch main  # Switch back to main
git commit --allow-empty -m "Subsequent commit"  # Another commit on main
git config --add receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore  # Allow direct pushes to the checked-out branch

The test then runs the tooling script, which tries to get the latest tag in the main branch:
LATEST_TAG=$(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))

... which is where the error ("fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD") occurs.
Would anyone be able to advise what the issue is, please?

The problematic line consists of 2 commands; can you separate them and show us their output? git rev-list --tags --max-count=1 and then git describe --tags <sha1_from_prev_command>? Which one produces the error?

Minor nit: receive.denyCurrentBranch is not a list, why --add in git config --add?

I wonder if this is a bare repo.

@eftshift0 In a bare repo the 2 commands work perfectly, no errors, 2nd command prints a tag. git commit --allow-empty doesn't work in a bare repo; error: "fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree".

Not shown in the question above, but the problem was to do with how I invoked Git in the following command (specifically, the "git rev-list" part):
LATEST_TAG=$(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))

Once I had fixed this, the BATS test worked correctly.

Add these lines in the initial setup to create the repository.
git init my_repo
cd my_repo

The complete working initial setup.
git init my_repo
cd my_repo

git remote add origin ../my_repo/.git  # Link to origin (if testing locally)
git switch --create main  # Create the main branch
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit"  # Initial commit to set HEAD

git tag v11.0.0  # Create a tag on the main branch

git switch --create release/12.0.0  # Create release branch
git commit --allow-empty -m "Commit for v12.0.0"  # Commit on release branch

git merge v11.0.0  # Merge tag onto the release branch

git switch main  # Return to main branch
git commit --allow-empty -m "Subsequent commit"  # Another commit on main
git config --add receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore  # Allow direct pushes

Then, run the tooling script.
